# File not found for file in src\resources accessed with ClassLoader.getSystemResource("file.txt")

Tags: java

I am trying to access a text file within my Java Netbeans project, but I keep getting file not found.

Please note that I've tried specifying the file with "src\ ....", "resources\ ...", and only using the file name.

This is my code:

```
static class Task extends TimerTask {
    // Load the directory as a resource
    URL dir_url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("word_list_moby_credits.txt");
    // Turn the resource into a File
    File f = new File(dir_url.getFile());

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
```

I'm getting

> File not found

on the last line of the code above.

This is my project:

[image]

[image]

Comment: A good first step would be inspecting `dir_url` and ensuring it matches the real location of the file.

Comment: @JLewkovich Thanks. So I mean the file is in the project directory in the screenshot above. I put it there manually. I checked again after your comment to make sure it's still there.

Comment: I meant debug the code and inspect `URL dir_url` at runtime and ensure it matches the location where you manually put the file

Comment: @JLewkovich Oh, I see thank you. Yes I will do that right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this to read words.txt in {Source Packages}/resources:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        URL url = Task.class.getResource("/resources/words.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
        System.out.println("" + scanner.next());
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In case you already have other main method and still want to keep this code outside a method, you can wrap it in a static block:

```
static class Task extends TimerTask {
   static {
        try {
            URL url = Task.class.getResource("/resources/words.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
            System.out.println("" + scanner.next());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I just use this way of referencing the file with my code then I get the same error. If I replace my code with this code block the IDE tells me there's an unreported exception IOException and doesn't give me an option to automatically fix it.

Comment: You can wrap this code in try {} catch(Exeption e) {} block. I have run this code on my Netbeans and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks. Idk why Netbeans still doesn't like it: http://imgur.com/a/6yHhG

Comment: You must put this code in a method such as: public static void main(String[] args) {}. Please see my update again.